# How can I save a Blob (audio) into the repo file system?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am recording user audio through the system mic and can successfully download it to the device doing the recording, but I would like to store this in my database through an API call. How would I send this audio blob to the back-end? The code below saves to the recording device's downloads folder.

```js
const addAudioElement = (blob: any) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "file name";
    a.href = url;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it to the database:

First, you create an object instance with File built-in API

```
const audio= new File([AudioBLOB], "file.mp3", {
    type: "audio/mpeg",
});
```

Then, you will add the file to FormData

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("audio", audio);
```

Finally, you will send the formData with an axios/fetch to the backend

```
await axios.post(endPoint,formData,{ "content-type": "multipart/form-data"});
```

In the backend, if you are using node.js or the next.js API, you can use a library like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

with multer you can access the uploaded audio, in the backend and save it to your database